# Import history and bookmarks from JSON

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I had to format the drive that Chromium was installed on.
My mistake: I exported my history and bookmarks using the 'Export History / Bookmarks to JSON / CSV * / XLS *' extension.

I admit that I do not know how to import these bookmarks / stories now. When I try to manually paste the contents of this JSON into the Bookmarks file in the Chromium config, everything is deleted after restarting. Maybe you have an idea how to import it?

This is an example JSON record created by the extension:

```
{ 
"index": 0,
"title": "stackoverflow",
"url": "https://stackoverflow.com",
"id": 8,
"parentId": "1",
"dateAddedLocal": "29.10.2017, 19:37:41",
"dateAddedUTC": "2017-10-29T18:37:41.989Z"
}
```